# How to port C ioctl() calls to Go

Tags: c, go, unix, system-calls, ioctl

I have the following code that I am porting from C to Go:

```
// Push modules into /dev/arp to enable it
// f is the file descriptor for /dev/arp
if (ioctl(f, I_PUSH, "tcp") == -1) {
    // Error handling, omitted for brevity
}
if (ioctl(f, I_PUSH, "udp") == -1) {
    // Error handling, omitted for brevity
}
if (ioctl(f, I_PUSH, "icmp") == -1) {
    // Error handling, omitted for brevity
}
```

I looked at the [`unix` package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix) and found that there are multiple `unix.Ioctl*` functions, but it is not clear which one (if any of them) I can use for these operations in Go.

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388088/how-to-ioctl-properly-from-golang), but the OP appeared to have a different [`ioctl`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) use case than I do. I don't think [`unix.IoctlSetInt`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#IoctlSetInt) satisfies my use case.

Which, if any, of the `unix.Ioctl*` functions will work for my use case?

If the answer to the above question is none of them will work, then what should I use for `op` and `arg` in my raw `syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_IOCTL, fd, op, arg)` call?

Comment: You need a (customized) wrapper function. See how the existing unix.Ioctl* functions are implemented (they're built by a "make a wrapper function" program, which is the generic way to do this, but you can make a much more specific wrapper of your own).

Comment: @torek, how could I pass the `"tcp"` string to `ioctl` from Go? None of the `Ioctl*` wrapper functions I looked at in the source code for the `unix` module have an example where this is done. (If you think I should ask this as a separate question, I am open to doing that.)

Comment: You could turn the Go string into a C string and pass the C string to your wrapper, or—far simpler—if you need this exact sequence of `ioctl`s, just pass the fd alone and have the C wrapper itself hardcode the three strings and ioctl arguments. (Then you don't need three separate error checks either, just have the C code return early on error.)