# Convert `ioctl` call in golang

Tags: go, io-uring

I'm trying to convert, or at least understand [this](https://github.com/axboe/liburing/blob/1c469ee303d0f458a6b039c9483865b3af248400/test/nvme.h#L41) `ioctl` call:

```
#define NVME_URING_CMD_IO   _IOWR('N', 0x80, struct nvme_uring_cmd)
```

Is there an equivalent of `_IOWR` in golang? maybe with the `unix` [package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#IoctlSetInt)?

Comment: Seems connected to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388088/how-to-ioctl-properly-from-golang

Comment: Have you actually tried to do `grep -r -E '#define\s+_IOWR' /usr/include/` on your system and then read the `ioctl.h` file it finds? I mean, the question as stated makes little sense as you've shown a definition of a C macro which ostensibly refers to another C macro (which may refer to other—all the way down to the elephants and the turtle). So you first have to come up with the "unwrapped" bit of C code for your question to have sense. Note that the definition you have shown does not look like an `ioctl` call.

Comment: Also youmight start with a common approach: create a no-brained C program which contains `#include <sys/ioctl.h>` and then contains the definition you've cited, and then declares a variable of type `NVME_URING_CMD_IO`. Then ask the preprocessor to expand all the macros—for `gcc` that will be `gcc -E yourprogramfile.c`. You will see what kind of thing all this gets unwrapped in the end.

Comment: The `_IOWR` and similar macros compile to a magic constant. You can't always get this constant directly from Go as the constant embeds the result of `sizeof` some C data type and not all C data types can be expressed in Go (unions are problematic in particular).

Comment: You can, however, run a C compiler over some C code that spits out the constant into a file that you can then incorporate into Go source code. But that still leaves you with the problem of setting up the C data structure. You can sometimes do the whole thing on a case-by-case basis, and that's generally what you find in cross-language ioctl packages.

Comment: thanks guys, I couldn't compile the project due to some local conflicts, but by following the code and thanks to your suggestions I managed to make it work. It turns out that although it was in the `ioctl.h` file no `ioctl` calls are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to convert it, thanks to help in comments:

```golang
const (
    IocNrBits           = 8
    IocTypeBits         = 8
    IocSizeBits         = 14
    IocNrShift          = 0
    IocRead     uintptr = 2
    IocWrite    uintptr = 2
)

const (
    IocTypeShift = IocNrShift + IocNrBits
    IocSizeShift = IocTypeShift + IocTypeBits
    IocDirshift  = IocSizeShift + IocSizeBits
)

func IOC(dir, t, nr, size uintptr) uintptr {
    return (dir << IocDirshift) |
        (t << IocTypeShift) |
        (nr << IocNrShift) |
        (size << IocSizeShift)
}

func IOWR(t, nr, size uintptr) uintptr {
    return IOC(IocRead|IocWrite, t, nr, size)
}

func NVME_URING_CMD_IO() uintptr {
    return IOWR('N', 0x80, 32)
}
```